# QNetworkProxy problem if user info is supplied without a password

Tags: qt5, qt6, qtnetwork

This is a really special case.

Let's say I'm using `QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy()`, with this proxy:

```
http://Ut4kX@sOK84JMNxXaZDWo@smartproxy.crawlbase.com:8088
```

As you can see, this specific proxy requires authentication, but it lacks a password.
I've tested it "by hand" and when asked for credentials, I just leave the password field empty.

However, it seems that QtNetwork *does not like it when a password is not supplied*.

Hence, I'm being forced to pass one (`QNetworkProxy::setPassword()`) to get a successful connection (any gibberish works).

Has anybody experienced this? Is there a more fancy solution?

Thanks. =)